# QucikFix Message validation failure

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I use QuickFixJ 1.5.3 and use FIX50SP2 for message validation. When I construct a simple MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh (W) from Verifix and send the message qucikfix rejects the message. The reject message says "Tag not defined for this message type" and RefTagID = 423 (Price type). When I remove this tag from the incoming message then it works without any issue. In that case I'm only transmitting the following tags - Symbol,NoMDEntries->MDEntryType,MDEntryPx

I checked the FIX50SP2.xml. There the Price type tag is correctly defined, but some how quickFixJ does not identify it and fails the validation.

Comment: Please add the exact FIX message that was sent and the reject message.

Comment: It was finally discovered that the 1.5.3 version does not support FIX50SP2. Luckily version 1.6.0 is released very recently that does not reject the above mentioned message.

Comment: Hi @SashikaXP, I added that solution as a community wiki answer for other searchers.  If you'd like, post that as the answer and accept it, and I can delete the community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> It was finally discovered that the 1.5.3 version does not support
>   FIX50SP2. Luckily version 1.6.0 is released very recently that does
>   not reject the above mentioned message.